# HiveQL to find the second largest salary from the employee table?

Tags: hive, hiveql

How to find the second largest salary from the employee table using HiveQl?

Comment: Easy: read some documentation about Hive & about SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of ties the accepted answer won't work. So below is my code which works in all situations. Just replaced `row_number` with `dense_rank` that's it. Want to know more about `dense_rank` then visit this [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2012/12/19/find-nth-highest-salary-using-ranking-functions/)

```
select * from  (SELECT dep_name,salary,DENSE_RANK() over(ORDER BY salary desc) as rank FROM department) as A where rank = 2;
```

OUTPUT:

```
+--------+------+----------+
|dep_name|salary|     rank |
+--------+------+----------+
|      CS| 30000|         2|
|   CIVIL| 30000|         2|
+--------+------+----------+
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT * from(select salary,row_number( ) 
    over (order by salary desc ) 
    as BLAH_no from table where group by salary) T where T.BLAH_no=2;
```

Comment: you can find detailed info. over here:https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/7660/how-to-find-nth-highest-salary-in-hive.html

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer on my own. Below is the HQL Query to get the second maximum salary from Employee table.

```
select firstname,salary from
    (select firstname, salary from employee sort by salary desc limit 2)
     result sort by salary limit 1;
```

Happy Learning!!

Comment: What about ties, i.e. if you have employees A, B, C with $4500 salary then employee D with $4200? Which one(s) or what is(are) "second"? B? D? or "$4200"?

Comment: Now read about analytic functions like `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`  0:-)